# Process in background is stopped

Tags: linux, background-process

I want to put a program in the background. I start it by executing `./IpLocations`. Then I suspend it with Ctrl + Z. When I call `bg` the program is in the background but it's still in Stopped state.

The program resumes when I type `fg`.

```
mini@m:~: ./IpLocations 
## [CTRL+Z] ##
[1]+  Stopped                 ./IpLocations

mini@m:~$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./IpLocations

mini@m:~$ bg
[1]+ ./IpLocations &

mini@m:~$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 ./IpLocations
```

Why is the program stopped afte calling `bg`?

How to resume a program in the background?

Comment: Another one: [What would stop a task from being run in the background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152515/108618) Also [A Deep Dive into the SIGTTIN / SIGTTOU Terminal Access Control Mechanism in Linux](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux) (note: I cannot fully judge the quality and accurateness of this article).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152515/108618 was very helpful. In conclusion I have to add `>/dev/null` when running the program. `./IpLocations > /dev/null`